# Ember component's sendAction doesn't bubble after destroyRecord

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In my Ember.js app, I have a controller called mailing-lists that has a component within it called mailing-lists-select. The mailing-lists controller passes into the component two actions, showSelectedMailingList and mailingListDeleted.

We expect that when these actions are invoked on the component, the actions should bubble up to the controller. However, it looks like only showSelectedMailingList action gets bubbled up when it is invoked in the component, while the mailingListDeleted action never bubbles up when we invoke it in the component.

The only difference between the two actions is that the sendAction for mailingListDeleted is invoked in the component after a destroyRecord call. Is this is known problem or is there a bug somewhere in my code?

Versions in use:

```
Ember: 1.11.2
Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.16.1
jQuery: 1.11.3
```

**mailing-lists.js controller**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedId: null,

  actions: {

    showSelectedMailingList: function(id) {
      //action bubbles up, execution reaches here
      this.set('selectedId', id);
    },

    deleteMailingList: function(record) {
      //execution never reaches here (???)
      //some code
    }
  }
});
```

**mailing-lists.hbs template**

```
<div>
{{#each model as |mailingList|}}
  {{mailing-lists-select-option
    mailingList=mailingList
    showSelectedMailingList='showSelectedMailingList'
    deleteMailingList='deleteMailingList'
  }}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

**mailing-lists-select-option.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  mailingList: null,

  actions: {

    showSelectedMailingList: function(id) {
      //execution reaches here
      this.sendAction('showSelectedMailingList', id);
    },

    deleteMailingList: function(mailingList) {
      var dat = this;

      mailingList.destroyRecord().then(function() {
        //execution reaches here
        dat.sendAction('deleteMailingList', mailingList);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**mailing-lists-select-option.hbs**

```
<li><a href="#" {{action 'showSelectedMailingList' mailingList.id}}>Show</a></li>
<li><a href="#" {{action 'deleteMailingList' mailingList}}>Delete</a></li>
```

Comment: Why are you destroying mailingList in component and then sending action to controller to do the same, you should only send action from your component and destroy mailing list with destroyRecord in controller.

Comment: Originally there were separate things we need to do in the component and the controller, but our workaround is to move all that logic into the controller. For this quesiton I was more wondering whether the sendAction bubbling from the component is affected by destroyRecord.

Comment: I am not sure, it's certainly not the best practice.

Comment: Is mailing List deleted when you call destroyRecord(), since it returns promise it may be that it's not resolved due to some error and since it does not enter your then function, sendAction is never called.

Answer (score 2):

Since destroyRecord() returns promise you may have some error that causes it to fail and never resolve so then() function is never called and so not sendAction() from it.
If this is not the case sendAction() had to be called, I tried something similar in my app and it works from destroyRecord().